# Use inputAccessoryView in WKWebView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, wkwebview

I've been looking for days how to use the `inputAccessoryView` method inside a WKWebView. I guess I could use the first responder ([`UIResponder.inputAccessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621119-inputaccessoryview)) as Apple Documentation says, but I have no idea of how this work. Plus, it's apparently a read-only property.

I'm not sure how to implement this feature inside `WKWebView` (or the first responder). Any help is needed .